# gradlew bootRun fails

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I've a web project in Eclipse to which I've added Gradle. There's an Application.java class which houses the main,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This resides inside `src/main/java/x/y/z`

I've a few problems here. 
1. The bootrun task doesn't show up in the gradle tasks. In the  same way if I rightclick the project and do a run as, boot run doesnt show up.

2. So when I do gradlew bootRun from the command line, I get the following error,

could not find or load main class from x/y/z/Application
I've tried adding the following to the build.gradle

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = "x.y.z.Application"
}
```

Still the same. Any help appreciated.